# How to configure qemu with a raw drive, but have it not fail if the drive is missing?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm using [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/en/), which uses [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) under the hood. I have a vm that needs to access drives directly, so I have [lines such as the following](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Manual:_vm.conf) in my `.conf`:

```
sata1: /dev/disk/by-uuid/f203be0a-4135-4964-a548-5095adf279ca,format=raw,backup=no
```

However, if I disconnect one of the drives, the vm will no longer power up, complaining that it can't find the drive. Which is fair enough, but how do I tell it to ignore the missing drive and continue regardless?

Normal computers don't fail simply because you've disconnected a non-essential drive, and I'd like my vm to be no different in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file config is processed line by line before VM or container start. If you disconnect the drive, you must delete or comment (#) that line before starting the VM again. If not, it will always fail.